# How To Debug a vscode extension's WebView javascript

Tags: javascript, webview, visual-studio-code, telerik, vscode-extensions

I am building a vscode extension, but I cannot set breakpoints in the Javascript in the WebView. Is there a way to debug the Javascript, even though the WebView is a separate process? Specifically, I am trying to incorporate a Telerik TreeView/TreeList and it is not displaying. The HTML and Javascript will display, in a self-contained data version, not using postMessage, if saved off to an HTML file and loaded into a browser. It is most likely a problem in my code, but I need a way to debug it. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

Use the following command: `Open Webview Developer Tools`

Comment: Press `ctrl + shift + p` in the vscode and type  `Open Webview Developer Tools`

Comment: Is it possible to launch Developer Tools along with starting webview (to be able to set breakpoint during its initialization)?

Comment: I figured out that if I put a console.log statement in my webview js then the message which gets printed comes with a link to the source code so I can set a breakpoint in the Webview Developer Tools side panel.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved my problem, but [a page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview#_inspecting-and-debugging-webviews) I had read 10 times explained how to debug a WebView in vscode. I should be able to figure it out from here. RTFM .