# Subsequent clicks on an element in webview panel are not passed through vscode api

Tags: webview, vscode-extensions

I'm creating the following webview panel in my vscode extension:

```js
webviewPanel = window.createWebviewPanel(
    this.id,
    title,
    viewColumn,
    {
        enableScripts: true,
    }
);

webviewPanel.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(props => console.log(props));

const nonce = getNonce();
webviewPanel.webview.html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="default-src 'none'; style-src ${this.webviewPanel.webview.cspSource}; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="${embeddedFile("panel.css")}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
    <script nonce="${nonce}" type="text/javascript" src="${embeddedFile("panel.js")}"></script>
</body>
</html>`;
```

content of `panel.js`:

```js
const filePathAnchor = document.getElementById("btn");
filePathAnchor.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
    vscode.postMessage({
        command: "click"
    });
});
```

When clicking the button in the panel, callback is executed as expected and `{command: "click"}` is logged. However any subsequent click is just ignored, as far as I can tell. Adding any `console` in the `js` file is not printing anywhere that I could find.

Comment: And about debugging the js code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613207/how-to-debug-a-vscode-extensions-webview-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `panel.js` to the following resolved the behavior (Calling `acquireVsCodeApi` only once). Still no idea why.

```js
const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();

const filePathAnchor = document.getElementById("btn");
filePathAnchor.addEventListener('click', () => {
    vscode.postMessage({
        command: "click"
    });
});
```

In case you are building the html view in a string and want a function to be called when an action happens on the view:

```js
private getViewScripts(): string {
    return `<script>
    vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();

    function searchPath() { 
        vscode.postMessage({
            command: 'alert',
            text: 'IT WORKS'
        })
    }
    </script>` ;
}
```